Using fisheye calibration to solve allsky images using OpenCV (fails)
I am using fisheye calibration to solve chessboard images using OpenCV. It fails for the calibration flag cv2.fisheye.CALIB_RECOMPUTE_EXTRINSIC, so I work around it. But once I get the parameters, the distortion is not looking good. I am attaching an image too.
From the Fisheye calibration
This is my code here:


chessboardsize = (13, 9)
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.1)
flags = ( cv2.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH + cv2.CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE + cv2.CALIB_CB_FILTER_QUADS)
# calibration_flags = cv2.fisheye.CALIB_RECOMPUTE_EXTRINSIC + cv2.fisheye.CALIB_CHECK_COND + cv2.fisheye.CALIB_FIX_SKEW
calibration_flags = cv2.fisheye.CALIB_CHECK_COND + cv2.fisheye.CALIB_FIX_SKEW

objp = np.zeros((1, chessboardsize[0]*chessboardsize[1], 3), np.float32)
objp[0, :, :2] = np.mgrid[0:chessboardsize[0], 0:chessboardsize[1]].T.reshape(-1, 2)
_img_shape = None

objpoints = [] # 3d point in real world space
imgpoints = [] # 2d points in image plane.
images = glob.glob('calibration_frames/*.jpg')  # Images

if len(images) == 0:
    raise ValueError("No images found in the specified directory.")

for fname in images:
    
    img = cv2.imread(fname)
    if img is None:
        print(f"Image {fname} cannot be read.")
        continue  # Skip if the image is not read properly
    if _img_shape == None:
        _img_shape = img.shape[:2]
    else:
        assert _img_shape == img.shape[:2], "All images must share the same size."

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Find the chess board corners
    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, chessboardsize, flags)
    # If found, add object points, image points (after refining them)
    if ret == True:
        objpoints.append(objp)
        cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,corners,(11,11),(-1,-1),criteria)
        imgpoints.append(corners)
        
        cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, chessboardsize, corners, ret)
        img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))
        plt.imshow(img_rgb)
        plt.title(f'Chessboard Corners: {fname}')
        plt.axis('off')
        plt.show()
    else:
        print(f"Chessboard corners not found in {fname}")

if len(objpoints) == 0 or len(imgpoints) == 0:
    raise ValueError("No valid images found for calibration.")

N_OK = len(objpoints)
K = np.zeros((3, 3))
D = np.zeros((4, 1))
rvecs = [np.zeros((1, 1, 3), dtype=np.float64) for i in range(N_OK)]
tvecs = [np.zeros((1, 1, 3), dtype=np.float64) for i in range(N_OK)]

 # Perform fisheye calibration
try:
    rms, _, _, _, _ = cv2.fisheye.calibrate(
        objpoints,
        imgpoints,
        _img_shape[::-1],
        K,
        D,
        rvecs,
        tvecs,
        calibration_flags,  # cv2.fisheye.CALIB_RECOMPUTE_EXTRINSIC throws error
        (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 1e-6)
    )

    print("Found " + str(N_OK) + " valid images for calibration")
    print("DIM=" + str(_img_shape[::-1]))
    print("K=np.array(" + str(K.tolist()) + ")")
    print("D=np.array(" + str(D.tolist()) + ")")

except cv2.error as e:
    print("Calibration failed:", e)


I have tried using normal camera calibrate too.  It looks like this:
From the normal camera calibration. I am trying to make it as better as possible as I will be detecting stars and patterns later with the distortion parameters.

I'd say it has done quite well at removing the fish eye distortion. What you are left with is a perspective vanishing point rectilinear grid problem (which can also be corrected for if you have a suitable square reference - like a chess board). I doubt it will matter for sky images though - are you sure the camera is sensitive enough?

crosspost: https://forum.opencv.org/t/trying-to-calibrate-allsky-camera-using-fisheye-calibration-fails/18237

@MartinBrown I will try to correct it with the rectilinear grid problem. Would you say the fisheye calibration (the first image) actually works? Yes, the camera is sensitive enough. I need to undistort the image to maintain the distance between the stars to solve their positions and monitor them throughout the night sky. I am trying to undistort it better to identify the stars.

How do you know if the calibration result are good or bad? What do you look at?
For example, if you are checking/evaluating something likes "straightness", please show its result directly rather than show only picture.

@fana I did the reprojection error which came out to be 0.18 which I think is good because it's close to 0.

You said something(related to calibration) is not looking good, and now, you say the calibration result is good. Assuming the calibration result is good, what is the current problem?

@fana The calibration using the cv2.fisheye.calibrate is not looking good. However, the calibration using cv2.calibrateCamera is good. I want the cv2.fisheye.calibrate to work, hoping that it would give better distortion parameters.

low repro error is necessary but not sufficient for a good calibration.
